# Fixing arch ubuntu multiboot

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled on my laptop. I installed Windows 10, and Arch. When I installed grub for Arch, I noticed something strange : my ubuntu partition wasn't found by os-prober. I then opened the parition where Ubuntu is installed by default(`/dev/sda3`), and saw that it maintains its separate `boot` folder. My actual ESP(`/dev/sda1`) is mounted into `/boot/efi` of `/dev/sda3`(the ubuntu partition). Moreover, Ubuntu is booted directly using it own efi executable, which resides in `efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` in `/dev/sda1`(ESP). Ubuntu maintains its own kernels in `/boot` of `/dev/sda3`, but Arch installed its kernels directly into `/dev/sda1`. So how can I clear up this mess and have a single grub stub inside `efi/grub` of `/dev/sda1`, which will manage both my Ubuntu and Arch installations, using their separate kernels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'd like to clear up some terminology: In the context of EFI boot loaders for Linux, "EFI stub" refers to a boot loader that's built into the Linux kernel itself, enabling the kernel to be launched as an EFI program. You seem to be using this term to refer to any EFI boot program, but that usage could create confusion.

That dealt with, `os-prober` on Arch *should have* detected your Ubuntu installation. I don't know why it didn't, but as Arch's `os-prober` is part of Arch, not Ubuntu, you might want to ask about that on an Arch forum. OTOH, if you follow my advice, you won't be using Arch's GRUB, so this point will become moot.

Arch gives its kernels fixed names that do not change when you update the kernel, whereas Ubuntu's kernel names include a version string, and therefore change when a new kernel is installed. This is important because GRUB configuration files, which refer to the kernel, are created by the OS that controls GRUB. Thus, if you use Arch's GRUB, you'll need to reconfigure GRUB in Arch whenever you update an Ubuntu kernel. This is likely to be awkward. If you use Ubuntu's GRUB, OTOH, its configuration will not need to be updated when you update an Arch kernel. (When you install a new Ubuntu kernel, Ubuntu's scripts will automatically update Ubuntu's GRUB.) Thus, of the two, I'd recommend using Ubuntu's GRUB, not Arch's GRUB.

You can switch to Ubuntu's GRUB by using `efibootmgr` in either distribution:

1. Type `sudo efibootmgr` to see a list of entries. Pay attention to the `BootOrder` line and to the `Boot####` entries for Arch and Ubuntu. The `BootOrder` line tells you the order in which the computer will try to launch specific boot entries. Given your OSes, chances are Arch's GRUB will be first in the `BootOrder` list.
2. Once you've identified the Ubuntu `Boot####` number, you can pass a new boot order to the firmware by using the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o 0004,0002,000A`. This sets the boot order to use `Boot0004` first, then `Boot0002` if that fails, and finally `Boot000A` if both of the earlier ones failed. The details will vary for you, of course; you should ensure that Ubuntu's entry is first. What comes after that is likely to be irrelevant, although I'd recommend ensuring that at least one known-working entry is in the list, so that the system will boot to *something* even if the Ubuntu entry fails.

After you reboot, Ubuntu's GRUB should appear, but it might or might not have an entry for Arch. You can run `sudo update-grub` to generate a fresh Ubuntu GRUB menu and try again. This might or might not detect Arch's kernel. If it doesn't, you can edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` or use [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) to add an entry for Arch. Something like the following should work:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    linux /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda5 ro quiet splash
    initrd /initramfs-linux.img
}
```

This is just a crude example and could likely be improved upon. If nothing else, you'll probably have to change the `root=/dev/sda5` option to point to Arch's true root (`/`) partition. You might examine Arch's GRUB configuration or ask for help on an Arch forum if you want to improve on this example, or if you have problems with it.

As an alternative to the preceding, you could use something other than GRUB. Most boot loaders will require more in the way of manual configuration than GRUB, but that manual configuration is likely to be easier than GRUB's manual configuration. See [my page on EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) for a rundown of what's available. My own [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) tends to be easier to configure for multi-boot scenarios because it actively scans for kernels every time it boots, so it doesn't suffer from the need to keep updating a configuration file with every kernel update. OTOH, because Arch's kernel name doesn't change, if you use Ubuntu's GRUB, you won't suffer from the usual multi-distribution GRUB problems, so rEFInd won't be an improvement on this score.

One final point: With your configuration, your Arch kernels are stored on your EFI System Partition (ESP). This is a common Arch configuration, but you should be sure that your ESP is big enough. Sometimes the ESP is as small as 100 MB (or conceivably even smaller), which may leave little extra space once your kernels are in place. You can use `df` to see how much space is used and available on a partition, as in `df /boot/efi`. If your ESP is nearly full, you may want to put your Arch kernels somewhere else. Although using the ESP to store kernels is a common practice in Arch, it's not necessary, so you can do something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight. The problem while executing `update-grub` from Ubuntu is, it doesn't really update the global grub configuration file, which resides in `/dev/sda1`'s `/grub/` directory. Instead, as I told before, it uses its own `boot` directory, and mounts the original ESP to `/boot/efi`. So `update-grub` results in updation of `grub.cfg` under `/dev/sda3/boot/grub`, not `dev/sda1/grub`. Hence, the result is not effective at all. Also, my ESP is 500MB, and `os-prober` in Arch is detecting Ubuntu now, I really don't know why it wasn't until this post.

Comment: Also, `os-prober` in Ubuntu is not able to find other OSes.

Comment: Since you have *two* Linux distributions installed, you have *two* GRUB configuration files, not a single "global" file. You have Arch's GRUB configuration file on the ESP and Ubuntu's GRUB configuration file on Ubuntu's root (`/`) directory. Which one matters depends on which GRUB is launched by default, which is determined by the EFI boot order (`BootOrder` in the `efibootmgr` output). Please re-read my answer with that in mind. Ubuntu's `os-prober` does detect other OSes, but I can't promise is will detect Arch, hence the suggestion to use GRUB Customizer or create a manual configuration.